# Wait for promise to resolve to within an emitter.on listener function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, eventemitter

When the `someevent` event is fired I simply want to wait for the promise to be resolved before continuing. But slowFunctionThatReturnsPromise takes a long time to resolve and the overall process shuts down before it is resolved. Therefore it is never completed. I would have thought using a `then` would wait for the promise to be resolved, but I can't figure out why it doesn't wait.

```
emitter.on('someevent', listener)


var listener = function()
{
    x.slowFunctionThatReturnsPromise()
        .then(function()
         {
             console.log('done');
         })
}
```

Comment: *Waiting* and *asynchronous* are things that are opposite to each other. *Synchronous* code will keep the process busy before continuing with any other code in the same call stack, while *asynchronous* code only gets called *after* the currently running call stack is completed.

Comment: i need the promise returned by `slowFunctionThatReturnsPromise` to be resolved before exiting the `listener` function

Comment: `then` callbacks are executed asynchronously, so by the very nature (and intention) of promises such callbacks will *not* be executed before returning the promise, but after the current code task has completed. So: not possible.

Comment: not even with `setImmediate`? https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_asynchronous_vs_synchronous

Comment: No, again, the part that says *"this happens asynchronously"* will be executed *after* all currently running code has been executed until an empty call stack is reached. Only then the event queue is processed to execute any pending asynchronous code.

Comment: For goodness sakes, if this is actually a mocha exiting issue, then please describe the REAL issue and show the REAL code.  We ALWAYS do better here if you show the real problem, not some abstracted version of code you created that hides the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it on "exit" event which node.js describes

> Listener functions must only perform synchronous operations. The
>   Node.js process will exit immediately after calling the 'exit' event
>   listeners causing any additional work still queued in the event loop
>   to be abandoned. In the following example, for instance, the timeout
>   will never occur:
>
> https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/process.html#process_event_exit

You can though handle graceful kill signal and then exit the process when you're ready.

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
    x.slowFunctionThatReturnsPromise().then(function() {
        process.exit(0);
    })
});
```

Comment: apologies, i was using exit as a (bad) example, the event name is actually something else

Comment: Ok. In that case you can't do it either since listeners in standard EventEmitter are synchronous. This event emitter might be better for you. https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-eventemitter

Comment: thanks for the link, that would certainly work, but unfortunately the event emitter i am working in is within mocha, and I don't want to modify mocha https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha

Comment: Can you please tell more about what exactly you need to do? How does it relate to mocha?

Comment: On test failure https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/lib/runner.js#L58 i need to perform a function that takes 10 seconds within the listener function, but the mocha process ends before the slow function does, even when using .then

Comment: What this slow function do? Does it need to be run for all failed tests? Can you have custom test reporter that receives information about all failed tests and do something with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137817/discussion-between-wookieb-and-jmccure).

Comment: Unfortunately it needs to be executed before the cleanup step of each test

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a `return` in front of `x.slowFunctionThatReturnsPromise()`?

Comment: Yes, but node `EventEmitter`s don't care what the listeners return so this will not affect behaviour.